# Xamarin - Task wait for input from custom dialog

Tags: android-asynctask, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I have a downloading Task which downloads data from web in 4 steps, which are defined as async Tasks and runs one by one. Now due to some change I need to capture a user input from a custom dialog in between task 2 and 3. I have written a function to capture input from AlertDialog. The problem is dialog displays in between but it just dont wait and halt processing and process continues without taking user input. The code is something like this:

```
async void button_click(......){
await function1();
await function2();
await function3();
await function4();
....do the data processing after that.
}

async Task<datatype> function1(){ ...processing step 1 }
async Task<datatype> function2(){

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
              .SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) =>
              {
                  string inputText = txtInput.Text;
              })
              .SetView(customView)
              .Show();

.... some more processing
}
```

Is there any way I can stop processing untill user input is received from AlertDialog OR any other way of doing the same?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

```cs
public Task<bool> ShowDialog()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) =>
        {
            string inputText = txtInput.Text;
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        })
        .SetView(customView)
        .Show();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Then you can do:

```cs
await function1();
await ShowDialog();
await function2();
```

Comment: Great answer. I am using this. However, one problem. I get the return from ShowDialog which is a bool in your example. This means the TaskCompletionSource had the result set. But, the dialog does not go away right away. For example, if you wanted to do more work and show another AlertDialog after, the first one stays shown, hiding the new one. It isn't until some time after or maybe the main, enclosing method runs to completion that the dialog finally goes away.

Comment: This works great and the same basic technique worked perfectly with a regular Dialog instead of an AlertDialog. If you do this then in the event handler for your close button you not only need to call SetResult but you also need to dismiss the Dialog. Since my Dialog needed to return a string I declared a TaskCompletionSource<string> and a return type of Task<string>.

Answer (score -1):

missing put task < bool >

```
public Task<bool> ShowDialog()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) =>
       {
           string inputText = txtInput.Text;
           tcs.SetResult(true);
       })
        .SetView(customView)
        .Show();
   return tcs.Task;
}
```